# How to keep an aberrant moderator in check?

Tags: discussion

In

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/265010/43191

Dave Tweed wrote:

@EMFields: The whole thing is moot anyway, since the question was deleted at the OP's request. I just want to remind you about the SE policy to "be nice". It should be possible to discuss this without insulting other users. – Dave Tweed♦ 21 mins ago

And, yet, the record reflects that it was

"deleted by Dave Tweed♦ 28 mins ago",

instead of by the OP.

Comment: [Why can't we all just... get along?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPMmC0UAnj0)

Comment: @dim: Because some of us would rather kill/die than lose face.

Answer (score 10):

`2016-10-22 15:57:34Z` question closed by 5 users.

`2016-10-22 16:07:32Z` flag by the O.P. :

> i messed it up .. maybe the question wasn't that clear **so please delete it** :)
>   [emphasis mine, N.A.]

An O.P. can not delete his own question if it has got answers with upvotes.
Dave had deleted the question at `2016-10-22 17:18:48Z` .

Fair enough.

Comment: So the OP decided to kow-tow instead of sticking to his guns?

Comment: @EMFi: The op had no "guns" to stick to.  The question was crap.  It's unfortunate that TCrosley wrote a nice explanation if taken in isolation, but that doesn't make the question any less crap.

Comment: Thanks for the reality check, and apologies to Dave Tweed.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy last week and somehow missed this whole conversation. Apology accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be going out of your way to find fault with moderator actions, or perhaps a particular moderator.  To understand what Dave Tweed wrote, we have to consider what you wrote first:

> It wasn't a crap question at all, as evidenced by tcrosley's 
> excellent positive answer, as opposed to your less than helpful flames 
> seeking, it seems, only to insult the OP for asking a question beyond your 
> ken.

That's when Dave responded (quite reasonably and with measured moderator authority):

> The whole thing is moot anyway, since the question was deleted at the OP's request. I just want to remind you about the SE policy to "be nice". It should be possible to discuss this without insulting other users.

There is no reason you should be upset at that response.

You then ask above:

> And, yet, the record reflects that it was "deleted by Dave Tweed♦ 28 mins ago", instead of by the OP.

Right, just like Dave said.  Dave didn't say that the OP deleted the question, but that it *"was deleted at the OP's request"*.  It seems the whole issue is a minor misreading of Dave's comment.  This is not something worthy of making a big deal about.

The bigger issue is that TCrosley wrote a really nice answer to something that wasn't asked.  Unfortunately, the question getting deleted caused that effort to be wasted.  That's a risk you take when answering a crappy question.

However, there is still something TCrosley can do about it, and I think he should.  He can ask the right question himself, then copy his existing answer there.  Answering your own question is allowed here, even encouraged in the right circumstances.  I've done it a couple of times myself.

Comment: **1.** I think it's important to point to abused authority and to confront bullies.  In this instance, Dave's admonition of my demeanor as being not nice glossed over ThePhoton's clearly abusive language used to demean and intimidate the OP.  **2.** What do you think the "right question" should have been?

Comment: @EMFi: There is no abused authority here, and *you* are being the bully.  Consider the -6 vote (currently) on your question as everyone else here standing up to the bully.

Comment: **1.** You say there's no abused authority, but since you're one of the most abusive people here, I'd say your opinion is decidedly less than objective and rather self-serving.  Plus, 6 downvotes means I only pissed off 6 people, for whatever reason but, more than likely, retaliatory responses for reminding them of their own bullying . **2.** Again I ask: what do you think should have been the "right question" for TCrosley to ask?